# Segmentation fault while running zend_hash_find()

Tags: php, gdb, coredump

I have written a simple php module and try to run the zend_hash_find() function. But I'm getting a strange segfault message.
Running on Centos 6.2 64bit (Under VM), php 5.4.0 (happened on 5.3.3 as well)

Here is the function:

```
void my_func(const char *fname,int fname_len TSRMLS_DC){
void *func;
char *funcname = estrndup( fname , fname_len ) ;

php_printf("Before find\n");

if (zend_hash_find(EG(function_table), funcname,  fname_len + 1, (void **) &func) == FAILURE)
    php_printf("not found");

php_printf("after find \n");
efree(funcname);
}
```

This is how the function is called

```
my_func("fopen",5 TSRMLS_CC);
```

I see the "Before find" message, then coredump. Here is gdb message

```
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/php/modules/mymod.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/php/modules/mymod.so
Core was generated by `php test.php'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000083457d in _zend_is_inconsistent (ht=0x0, 
file=0xcd2b68 "/home/user/php/php-5.4.0/Zend/zend_hash.c", line=919)
at /home/user/php/php-5.4.0/Zend/zend_hash.c:54
54      if (ht->inconsistent==HT_OK) {
...skipped...
```

Anybody has any idea why this could be happening?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of zend_hash_find() is correct, I'm using it the same way in production without any problems. The gdb message says that the hash table (function_table) is NULL, so I suppose that the problem is with the initialization of your module. If you paste the full source, we might help :-)

BTW estrndup is not necessary in your case

Comment: This code is running in PHP_MINIT stage. Is it possible, that function_table is not yet initialized?

Comment: Can you test with CG(function_table) instead of EG(function_table)?